# Phaser & Django: Place canvas inside div

Tags: html, django, canvas, phaser-framework

I'm trying to embed a Phaser game into a Django application, but struggling with the most basic of operations to get started: Making sure the canvas is placed inside a particular div as to center it on the middle of the page.

From what I could gather, for this to work, I should simply specify the parent div. However, whenever I specify the parent div, the canvas is nowhere to be found. When I leave out the line again, it reappears, but outside the layout.

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h2>{{ title }}.</h2>
<h3>{{ message }}</h3>

<div id='phaser-canvas'></div>

{% endblock %}

<script>
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    parent: 'phaser-canvas',
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload() {
}

function create() {
}

function update() {
}
</script>
```

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your html file extends your `app/layouts.html`. That `layouts.html` has a content block in which the content of your content block gets inserted. But as all the rest of your code is not within that block, it does not get inserted to `layouts.html`.

Create more blocks in your `layouts.html` like one for styles, one for javascript etc. Then put your code also in these blocks. Because only what's inside those blocks gets transferred to the template which is to extend.

layout.html:

```
{% block styles %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
{% block javascript %}
{% endblock %}
```

your template:

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h2>{{ title }}.</h2>
<h3>{{ message }}</h3>

<div id='phaser-canvas'></div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascript %}
<script>
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    parent: 'phaser-canvas',
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload() {
}

function create() {
}

function update() {
}
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Ah! Gotcha... But isn't my simple(r) mistake to put the script block outside of the contents block? When I placed it inside of that, it started working again, but this time within the div.

Comment: Sure, that's working too. But as the convention is to put the javascript at the bottom of your html file for better loading times, I gave you the option that can assure that. Maybe your `layouts.html` has more html code after the `{% block content %}`, something like a footer maybe, then your javascript would be inserted before the footer html. Please consider accepting the answer as correct here in stackoverflow